# Understanding for loops in in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to understand for loops totally. I made my research and understand a little.

I Know loops like

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { console.log(i) }
```

Which means continue to increment `i` starting from `0` as log as `i` is less than `5`

I also know loops like

```
var a = [];
a[5] = 5;
for (var x in a) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

Which means loop for x in a and would log 5;

Was searching playing around researching and then i see something like

```js
function aNumber() {
  var aInt = 521;
  var intString = aInt.toString();
  var intLength = intString.length;
  var result = 0;
  for (var i in intString) {
    result += Math.pow((+intString[i]), intLength);
  }
  console.log(result);
  //... 

}

aNumber();
```

I understand the conversion of `int` to `string`. But the loop is new to me. 
I know what the `Math.pow()` function does like it take to parameters (Math.pow(2,2) is same as 2**2) and the `+` in `+intString` passes the `string` as an `int` What i don't really understand is this part here

```
result += Math.pow((+intString[i]), intLength);
```

Its making the whole `loop` look confusing.

Can someone help explain it for me in simple terms just like i explained the others? Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you populated your question with a value for `aInt` instead of leaving those periods.

Comment: a string of length 3 has ... `0`, `1`, `2` as properties - but it could have more than that with bad code :p

Comment: Ok @dwjohnston. ill do that.

Comment: @dwjohnston i think you changed the variable name intString to aString which is making it more confusing

Comment: so, you understand what Math.pow is doing ... so, it's the `result +=` that confuses you? that's just shorthand for `result = result +`

Comment: I editted your question to be a runnable snipped, but as @Amitchauhan points out - it looks like you've named a variable wrong - so it would be helpful if you fixed that.

Comment: with `aInt = 521` that's just 5**3 + 2 ** 3 + 1 ** 3 = 134?

Comment: Whoops, my bad.

Comment: @JaromandaX I just figured that out but i need a broken down explanation so i understand what is actually happening

Comment: I also need to know how the `+intString[i]` is working

Comment: but you understand everything else in that line - at least, you say you do

Comment: intString is a string ... intString[i] is the i'th character in intString ... e.g. if intString is `9876` intString[2] is 7

Comment: @JaromandaX Please what function in that code is responsible for the addition `aInt = 521` amount to `5**3 + 2**3 + 1**3` or does this happen by default?

Comment: the for loop with result +=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for..in` loops iterate over the *enumerable property names* on the object (including properties inherited from the prototype). Because strings' enumerable properties are always their numeric indicies and nothing else, the line:

```
for (var i in intString)
```

can be replaced with

```
for (let i = 0; i < intString.length; i++)
```

while leaving the rest of the code the same, and it will perform identically. The `intString[i]` expression just refers to the current character being iterated over.

But I wouldn't recommend using `for..in` loops in most cases - it's not hard to confuse with `for..of` (which is quite different), and array methods are often nicer to work with. For example, the code that generates the `result` in your code can be replaced with the use of `Array.prototype.reduce`, which can generate the `result` at once, without any reassignment:

```js
const intString = '521';
const intLength = intString.length;
const result = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  intString,
  (a, intChar) => a + (intChar ** intLength),
  0 // initial value of accumulator a
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce.call` - while that is probably more technically correct, you can do `[].reduce.call`

Comment: That requires creating an empty array though, which can also lead to confusion, or so some have said, so I prefer referring to the prototype method over shorthand

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now. Also thanks for making me realize there is a `for..let` and `for of` loop. I guess i need to make more research.